# nginx password protection of folder

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to get a password protected folder setup on my server (using nginx). I have tried it like so:

```
    location / {
        root   /srv/www/steampunkjunkies.net/www;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location /cgi-bin/admin {
        satisfy any;
        allow  81.174.134.133;
        deny   all;
        auth_basic "Administrator Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/steampunkjunkies.net/htpasswd;
    }
```

...but the problem with that, is that once you login - it doesn't execute this code a bit further down:

```
    location ~ \.cgi$ {
        gzip off;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.cgi;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/steampunkjunkies.net/www/cgi-bin/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

(so you just get a file download)

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to do. Any suggestions? (this is my first time password protecting a folder on Nginx... but I've done it a ton of times on Apache)

**UPDATE:** As per a suggestion, I've now got:

```
location /cgi-bin/admin {
    satisfy any;
    allow  81.174.134.xxx;
    deny   all;
    auth_basic "Administrator Login";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/mysite.net/htpasswd;

    location ~ \.cgi$ {
        gzip off;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.cgi;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/mysite.net/www/cgi-bin/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

The IP part works fine:

```
    satisfy any;
    allow  81.174.134.xxx;
    deny   all;
```

(if I change the IP to something that is not mine, then I get the popup... otherwise it lets me in ok)

The problem is with the popup password auth box. I enter the details (correctly), and it then goes away - but I'm then presented with a `403 Forbidden` error for some reason. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that all location blocks are separate here, and nginx selects the location based on first match.

You can solve the issue by including the `location ~ \.cgi$ {` block inside the `location /cgi-bin/admin {` block too, like this:

```
location /cgi-bin/admin {
    satisfy any;
    allow  81.174.134.133;
    deny   all;
    auth_basic "Administrator Login";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/steampunkjunkies.net/htpasswd;
    location ~ \.cgi$ {
        gzip off;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.cgi;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/steampunkjunkies.net/www/cgi-bin/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Kikanen Thanks. That *almost* works. For some reason, after entering the correct user/pass, it then presents me with a 403 error (please see my revise OP to see the current code I'm using).